# Quadratic function implementation error in R's nlme

Tags: r, nlme, quadratic

I'm trying to fit a quadratic function to an HLM  model using R's `nlme`.

My data looks like this:

```r
Data <- structure(list(X = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 22L, 23L), 
  userId = c("0014","0014", "0014",  "0014", "0059", "0059"),
 who_score = c(24L, 60L,  40L, 48L, 80L, 92L),
response_date = c("2021-06-02 00:00:00",  "2021-06-22 00:00:00", 
   "2021-07-07 00:00:00", "2021-07-22 00:00:00",  "2021-08-05 00:00:00", "2021-08-23 00:00:00"),
 previous_response_date = c("2021-06-02 00:00:00",  "2021-06-02 00:00:00",
  "2021-06-22 00:00:00", "2021-07-07 00:00:00",  "2021-07-29 00:00:00", "2021-08-05 00:00:00"), 
   days_since_last_response = c(0,  20, 15, 15, 7, 18),     user_join_date = c("2021-06-02", "2021-06-02",  "2021-06-02",                                      "2021-06-02", "2021-07-29", "2021-07-29"), 
  night = c(0,  0, 0, 0, 0,   0), 
 morning = c(0, 31, 14, 28, 14, 20), 
  evening = c(0,  9, 11, 11, 10,                                                                                                                                                   13), 
  noon = c(0, 12, 20, 15, 10, 21), 
  total_daily_incoming = c(0,  52,45, 54, 34, 54), 
   active_day = c(0, 13, 13, 13, 3, 15), 
   response_ind =  c(0L,  1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L), 
 id = c("0014",  "0014", "0014",  "0014",  "0059",  "0059"), 
  utcOffset = c(-5, -5, -5, -5, -4, -4)), 
   row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My model is as follows.

```
mod4 <-
  lme(
    who_score ~ response_ind + I(response_ind^2) + 
   total_daily_incoming + active_day +  
      active_day * total_daily_incoming,
    random =  ~ response_ind + I(response_ind^2) | userId,
    data = Data1,
    method = "ML",  control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000)
  )
summary(mod4)
intervals(mod4)
```

but no matter what I do I keep getting this error

> Error in lme.formula(who_score ~ response_ind + I(response_ind^2) + total_daily_incoming +  :
> nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
> message = singular convergence (7)

I have tried increasing the number of iterations, dropping from the data participants with less then 3 observations, but nothing works.
Help...

Thank you

Comment: Please share a part of your data using `dput(head(Data1))`.

Comment: Your structure output is somehow broken: There are only 5 `userID`s included but the dataframe has 6 rows. Is this intentional?

Comment: I think we're probably not going to be able to answer this without a fully reproducible example ([mcve]) ....  using `poly()` *might* help (`who_score ~ poly(response_ind, 2) +  active_day * total_daily_incoming, random =  ~ poly(response_ind, 2) | userId`; `*` includes the main effects as well as the interaction)

Comment: @MartinGal  I just took out the real user ID, cause of privacy concerns, clearly my data has more then 5 or 6, i added another one to the list.